# How to match a hyphen in bash

Tags: regex, bash

Part of my script takes in all parameters and looks for any flag options.  I'm trying to save these into my array, but it doesn't seem to be matching.  I can't figure it out, what am I missing?

```
#!/bin/bash
ALL_PARAMS=( "$@" )

ARGUMENTS=()

OPTIONS=()

for i in ${ALL_PARAMS[@]}

do

    if [ $i == ^- ]
    then
        ARGUMENTS+=($i)
    else
        OPTIONS+=($i)
    fi
done

echo ${ARGUMENTS[@]}
echo ${OPTIONS[@]}
```

Comment: Do you need `$i =~ ^-` to do a regex match, instead of `==` ? (And maybe ^-$ to match the entire string instead of just the start)

Comment: Yeah I messed up the syntax, that ended up working.  thank you!

Comment: You should also double-quote variable references (for instance `for i in "${ALL_PARAMS[@]}"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` command (`[`) does not do Regex matching, the `bash` keyword `[[` does.

You need:

```
[[ $i =~ ^- ]]
```

Also note that, you need Regex operator `=~` instead of equality operator `==`.

Comment: Of course, regex is overkill. A simple pattern match with `-*` would be fine.